# Displaying elements on my page depending on the page width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to adjust elements displayed on my view depending on the width of the page. Let's say the page width is greater than 800 px, then I would like to display div A + div B (see picture below).

[image]

But if the page width is less or equal than 600 px,then I would like to display only div A.

[image]

It has to be dynamic. So If the user resize the window, the div B must be showed or hided.

A jQuery solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What if the page is 700px wide?

Comment: If the page width is 700 px, then only show div A. The div B must be showed starting from 800px.

Comment: So is your question ["How to get the width of the document or browser with jQuery"](http://api.jquery.com/width/) or ["How to hide a div with jQuery"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+hide+a+div+with+jquery)?

Comment: @nnnnnn: It's "How can I make the jQuery hammer solve all my problems?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in CSS, using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries)!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) { 
    #b {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/vkG5T/)

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'll post another question for a more advanced technic.

Comment: interesting, but not good support yet. http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries (IE8 is still considered by many to be a "current" browser)

Comment: @Kae - at my workplace I'm stuck with IE7 - not allowed to use any other browsers. (At home I use XP so I can't go to IE9, but at home I'd rather use Chrome and FF anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'd like non-javascript users to see both A and B:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $divB = $('....'); // Define div B here using selectors

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 800) {
            $divB.hide();
        }
        else {
            $divB.show();
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: Whoops, didn't see that you wanted it to be dynamic. Changed.

Doing it in CSS as Eric says is a better option than jQuery, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  var $body=$(document.body), width=$body.outerWidth(), c='large';
  if (width<600) {
    c='small';
  }
  else if (width<800) {
    c='medium';
  }
  $body.addClass(c);
});
```

then use `body.small`, `body.medium` and `body.large` in your CSS to provide different layouts.