# Dynamically adding or removing columns in a table based on the page width

Tags: jquery, html, css

In another question, I have a solution for showing or hiding a div based on the page width.

[Displaying elements on my page depending on the page width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201061/displaying-elements-on-my-page-depending-on-the-page-width)

Now, I would like a more advanced technic where we show or hide columns in a table based on the page width.

Here is an example of table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="col1">aaa aaaa</td>
        <td id="col2">bbbb bbb</td>
        <td id="col3">ccccc</td>
        <td id="col4">ddd dddd ddd ddd</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let's say:

- I would like to display `col1` only if page width is greater that **800px**.
- I would like to display `col2` only if page width is greater that **830px**.
- I would like to display `col3` only if page width is greater that **860px**.
- I would like to display `col4` only if page width is greater that **900px**.

It has to be dynamic so if the user resize the window, the content has to be shown/hidden.

Do you see what I would like to achieve? **Is there a better way of doing this?**

Thanks.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like you're using tables for layout there. One row table, with an id for each "column". Does your table have multiple rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
    #coll1 {
        display:none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) { 
    #coll2 {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

... and so forth, should probably do it.

**Edit:**
Note the limited browser support for media queries in older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

First calculate the window width and store it in a local variable like this

```
var width = $(window).width();
```

Then write a function to toggle the display of columns with your logic(what to display and what not to display) like below..

```
 function toggleEles()
 {
   $('#col1,#col2,#col3,#col4').hide();
   if( width >= 900  )
   {
         $('#col1,#col2,#col3,#col4').show();
   }
  // Write other conditions here..
 }
```

Then call this function on document.ready and on resize events as shown below

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
   toggleEles();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get the width of the screen:

```js
var screenWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
if(screenWidth < 1024)
{
    document.getElementById("col4").style.display = "none";
}
```

Then you will have to catch the event every time the screen is resized and hide/show accordingly.

Not sure how to do this in JQuery, but I belive there is an event for it.